# How can I automatically update column in datagridview base on the other column input

Tags: c#

I have a datagridview `dgvBlood` and I have 4 columns `Result`, `RangeFrom`, `RangeTo`, `Status`. I just want to have a `Status` to be `Normal or Abnormal` based on the input in `Result`. `If Result >= RangeFrom && Result <= RangeTo`  then `Result = "Normal" else "Abnormal"` `RangeFrom and RangeTo` is already given. User will just input `Result` and I just want to update it once the user has input.

Here's my sample code. And any help is appreciated.

```
private void dgvBlood_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    Double From = Convert.ToDouble(dgvBlood.CurrentRow.Cells["RangeFrom"].Value.ToString());
    Double To = Convert.ToDouble(dgvBlood.CurrentRow.Cells["RangeTo"].Value.ToString());
    Double Result = Convert.ToDouble(dgvBlood.CurrentRow.Cells["Result"].Value.ToString());

    String value = "Normal";
    String valueAb = "Abnormal";

    if (Result >= From && Result <= To)
    {
        dgvBlood.CurrentRow.Cells["Status"].Value = value;
    }
    else
    {
        dgvBlood.CurrentRow.Cells["Status"].Value = valueAb;
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is the issue that you are facing with this current code? are you getting any errors

Comment: What is the DataSource for your datagridview? You can achieve this in RowBound. But that is always slow. If your condition is fix; how about calculating the value of the column in DataTable and then binding it to DataGridView?

Comment: i dont have any error but my code is not functioning after i input RangeFrom and Range To, Result is still blank.

Comment: @AnandJayantJoshi I am using binding source with my datagridview.

Comment: in if and else condition it should be `["Result"]` instead of `["Status"]`

Comment: So, if you have a DataTable as your datasource I would recommend to get it pre-calculated to avoid unnecessary load. Or you want to change it on the fly depending on user's input?

Comment: @DarshanPatel, one more thing i have column Status and that column is where the output will go. Result is the initial input and this result will get the Status normal if the Result will satisfy that condition.

Comment: @AnandJayantJoshi i just want to load the Status base on users input. as the user input it will get the Status.

Comment: Web/ Windows app?

Comment: @AnandJayantJoshi Windows app

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        Double From = Convert.ToDouble("0"+dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["RangeFrom"].Value);
        Double To = Convert.ToDouble("0" + dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["RangeTo"].Value);
        Double Result = Convert.ToDouble("0" + dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Result"].Value);

        if (Result >= From && Result <= To)
        {
            dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Status"].Value = "Normal";
        }
        else
        {
            dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Status"].Value = "Abnormal";
        }
    }
```

You will have to put in a condition to check on which column change, status should change. Currently it will check for change in any cell.

Comment: this won't work, because i have other column that is combobox, and when I try this it has an error prior to my combobox column.

Comment: Ideally it should work. What is that column? Could you please update your question? I have tried adding a combobox and worked pretty well for me. What is the error you are getting?

Comment: i have a column id, and that value of that is from database, so i have value and display member for that column Sir.

Comment: That should not make any difference. What is the error you are getting after using this code piece?

Comment: i solved my own problem, thanks for your time and for your help Sir. I am working with the new problem hehehe. this datagridview is so hard